# Dedupe one new row against existing dataset

Tags: python, python-dedupe, dedupeplugin

I'm using [dedupe python library](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe).

Any code sample will do, for [example this](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/tree/master/csv_example).

Let's say I have a trained `deduper` and used it it to deduplicate a dataset successfully.

Now I add one new row to the dataset.

I want to check if this new row is a duplicate or not.

Is there a way to do that in dedupe (without reclassifying the whole dataset)?

**Update**: 
I have tried @libreneitor suggestion, but I just get `No records have been blocked together. Is the data you are trying to match like the data you trained on?` Here's my code ([csv file](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/blob/master/tests/datasets/restaurant-nophone-training.csv)):

```
import csv
import exampleIO
import dedupe

def canonicalImport(filename):
    preProcess = exampleIO.preProcess
    data_d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for (i, row) in enumerate(reader):
            clean_row = {k: preProcess(v) for (k, v) in
                         viewitems(row)}
            data_d[i] = clean_row
    return data_d, reader.fieldnames

raw_data = 'tests/datasets/restaurant-nophone-training.csv'

data_d, header = canonicalImport(raw_data)

training_pairs = dedupe.trainingDataDedupe(data_d, 'unique_id', 5000)

fields = [{'field': 'name', 'type': 'String'},
              {'field': 'name', 'type': 'Exact'},
              {'field': 'address', 'type': 'String'},
              {'field': 'cuisine', 'type': 'ShortString',
               'has missing': True},
              {'field': 'city', 'type': 'ShortString'}
              ]

deduper = dedupe.Gazetteer(fields, num_cores=5)
deduper.sample(data_d, 10000)
deduper.markPairs(training_pairs)
deduper.train(index_predicates=False)

alpha = deduper.threshold(data_d, 1)

data_d_test = {}
data_d_test[0] = data_d[0]
del data_d[0];

clustered_dupes = deduper.match(data_d, threshold=alpha)
clustered_dupes2 = deduper.match(data_d_test, threshold=alpha) <- exception here
```

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I'm facing a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

You can [`match`](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#Dedupe.match) a new row against your existing [`Dedupe`](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#dedupe-objects).

But if you already achieved a deduplicated dataset you can use [`Gazetteer`](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#gazetteer-objects) to add more unique data and then call [`match`](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#Gazetteer.match) again.

Comment: When I match 1 new row I get `No records have been blocked together. Is the data you are trying to match like the data you trained on?` error, despite the fact that it's very similar to the data that I matched previously.

Comment: I get the same error with `Gazetteer`. I call `match` and pass original dataset. After that I call `match` with just one row. I'm sure this one row is a duplicate. but I get this error. Do I call it wrong?